# Why am I getting a "vector iterator + offset out of range" error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

The following code is causing this error:

```
if (bestLine.size() > searchDepth - depth)
    bestLine.erase(bestLine.begin(), bestLine.end() - searchDepth - depth);
```

When I checked the value of `searchDepth - depth` at the time of the error, it was `0`.

So essentially,

```
if (bestLine.size() > 0)
    bestLine.erase(bestLine.begin(), bestLine.end());
```

is causing this error. (Or not. See comments below.)

To my knowledge the above code should erase the entire vector, which is the desired behavior in this case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you replace the first code with second code (which you think is essentially same), and see if the error still comes?

Comment: Good idea. No, I didn't receive an error. Now I'm really confused. I added `cout << searchDepth-depth;` before these two lines and saw two zeros before the debug assertion.

Comment: Try adding parentheses to your expression `bestLine.end() - (searchDepth - depth)`

Comment: I just tried that, and now it works. Thank you. I don't understand why that had an effect, however. The order of operations appears the same either way.

Comment: It does matter, `10 - (8 - 8)` is not the same as `(10 - 8) - 8`

Comment: @Blastfurnace: You should write that as an answer.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Thank you. Of course. That's what I get for doing homework at 4 in the morning...

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Thanks. I was unable to add my own answer for another 8 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding parentheses to your expression: `bestLine.end() - (searchDepth - depth)`. The result is very different if simply evaluated left-to-right.

Comment: How come this fixes the error and what I have suggested doesn't?

Comment: @izomorphius: Because you might subtract too much, going past the beginning. This subtracts the minimal amount. (Consider if `end - begin` was `5`, `searchDepth` was `10`, and `depth` was `10`.)

Answer (score 1):

You check if bestLine.size() is greater then searchDepth - depth, but then you substract searchDepth + depth. Change the sign before depth in the subtraction:
`bestLine.erase(bestLine.begin(), bestLine.end() - searchDepth *+* depth);`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I'm afraid. I receive the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a coding problem, but a math one.

Problematic math:

```
   bestLine.end() - searchDepth - depth
=> bestLine.end() + (-1) * searchDepth + (-1) * depth
=> bestLine.end() + (-1) * (searchDepth + depth)
=> bestLine.end() - (searchDepth + depth)
```

So, rather than trying to erase (searchDepth - depth) elements, you were trying to erase (searchDepth + depth) elements.

Correct math:

```
  bestLine.end() - (searchDepth - depth)
```